# How to get negative keyword list from a campaing using Google Adwords API

Tags: python, google-ads-api, google-reporting-api

When you set up a campaign in google adwords you can add negative keywords to it so that the searchquery may not match your campaign if it has the negative keyword.

I want to extract the list of the negative keywords per each campaign. In the documentation I was able to [find this example](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/negative-keywords-shared-sets#retrieving_negative_keywords):

```
def retrieve_negative_keywords(report_utils)
  report_definition = {
    :selector => {
      :fields => ['CampaignId', 'Id', 'KeywordMatchType', 'KeywordText']
    },
    :report_name => 'Negative campaign keywords',
    :report_type => 'CAMPAIGN_NEGATIVE_KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT',
    :download_format => 'CSV',
    :date_range_type => 'TODAY',
    :include_zero_impressions => true
  }

  campaigns = {}

  report = report_utils.download_report(report_definition)
  # Slice off the first row (report name).
  report.slice!(0..report.index("\n"))

  CSV.parse(report, { :headers => true }) do |row|
    campaign_id = row['Campaign ID']

    # Ignore totals row.
    if row[0] != 'Total'
      campaigns[campaign_id] ||= Campaign.new(campaign_id)
      negative = Negative.from_csv_row(row)
      campaigns[campaign_id].negatives << negative
    end
  end

  return campaigns
end
```

Which is written in Ruby and there are no Python examples for this task. There is also [a report for the negative keywords](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-negative-keywords-performance-report) but it holds no metrics and I can't use it to retrieve the list of negative keywords per each campaign.

I am using this structure to query the database:

```
report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                        .Select('CampaignId', 'Id', 'KeywordMatchType', 'KeywordText')
                        .From('CAMPAIGN_NEGATIVE_KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                        .During('LAST_7_DAYS')
                        .Build())
```

But querying it gives an error:

> googleads.errors.AdWordsReportBadRequestError: Type: QueryError.DURING_CLAUSE_REQUIRES_DATE_COLUMN

When I add `Date` it throws the same error.

Has anyone been able to extract the negative keyword list per campaign using Python with the Google Adwords API reports?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `DURING` clause when querying `CAMPAIGN_NEGATIVE_KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` as that report is a [structure report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/zeroimpression-structure-reports#structure_reports), meaning it doesn't contain statistics. If you remove the `During()` call and just do

```python
report_query = (googleads.adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                .Select('CampaignId', 'Id', 'KeywordMatchType', 'Criteria')
                .From('CAMPAIGN_NEGATIVE_KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                .Build())
```

you'll get the list of all negative keywords per campaign.

If you think about it, this makes sense—negative keywords *prevent* your ads from being shown, so metrics like impressions or clicks would be meaningless.